# building a nested array from a flat one - explanation

Tags: php, arrays

if someone could explain, please what the line:

```
$ref[$i] =& $ref[$p][$i]['ch'];
```

does in the following code:

```
<?php
$retv = array();

array_push($retv, array('record-id' => 1, 'record-parent' => 0));
array_push($retv, array('record-id' => 2, 'record-parent' => 1));
array_push($retv, array('record-id' => 7, 'record-parent' => 0));
array_push($retv, array('record-id' => 8, 'record-parent' => 7));
array_push($retv, array('record-id' => 9, 'record-parent' => 8));


$ret = array('root'=>array());
$ref[0] =& $ret['root'];

foreach($retv as $row) {
   $p=$row['record-parent'];
   $i=$row['record-id'];

   $ref[$p][$i] = array('data'=>$row,'ch'=>array());
   $ref[$i] =& $ref[$p][$i]['ch'];
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($ret); echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Thanks a lot.
Wojciech

Answer (score 1):

It sets `$ref[0]` as a reference to `$ret['root']`

Which means whatever happens to one of them, happens to **both** of them

Demo: http://codepad.org/6Qge3WOw

Comment: nice, I understand the meaning of =& operator, but why exactly is used in such a way "$ref[$i] =& $ref[$p][$i]['ch'];" ?